# Проверка актуальности данных на сервере

Tags: http, okhttp

Допустим, я запросом к серверу получаю ответ в виде json. Можно ли как-то определить заранее, что данные на сервере не менялись, чтобы повторно не загружать в клиент один и тот же ответ?

Comment: записать результат в сессию и сравнивать с тем что пришло.

Comment: "записать результат в сессию" - Вы имеете ввиду, что все равно придется повторно передавать тело ответа на клиент?

Comment: Можно считать и передавать с запросом хеш клиентских данных. Потом сервре посчитает хеш своих данных и сравнит их. Если хеши совпадут -  сервер возвращает пустой json - объект, и это служит признаком того, что данные не изменились.

Comment: Ровно для таких случаев есть [кеширующе заголовки](https://html5.by/blog/cache/), а конкретно я бы использовал ETag. Браузер отправляет запрос с запомненным ETag, и сервер, если ничего не поменялось, скажет "ничего не поменялось", и браузер вытащит данные из своего кеша. Экономия трафика, но минимальный запрос, конечно отправится. Второй способ - кешировать на год, а на странице писать версию `/data.json?ver=1000`, и менять ее только если данные реально поменялись. Тогда вообще второго запроса не будет. Вместо версии можно вписывать md5 хеш от содержимого файла.

Comment: S.H., TotalPusher, спасибо за решение! записал в ETag хеш файла, теперь осталось разобраться - почему запрос с хедером If-None-Match со значением хеша возвращает 200, а не 304, но это тема другого вопроса =)

Comment: Кто генерирует этот тег? Если веб-сервер, например Nginx, и это файл, то он просто берет его хеш, и проблем не должно быть. А если этот тег генерирует скрипт, то есть просто отдает этот заголовок + тело, то нужно еще доработать этот скрипт на предмет обработки `If-None-Match`, веб-сервер это не сделает за вас, потому что сам не знает, поменялись динамические данные или нет (а вот со статичными файлами он знает). Если это так, то либо дорабатывайте скрипт, либо делайте механизм с кеширующим прокси (тот же Nginx или Varnish). Плюс покажите все заголовки, может веб-сервер сработал на другой.

Comment: Да, Вы верно предположили - тег генерирует скрипт на php: header('ETag: '.hash_file('md5', $filename)); Спасибо, попробую разобраться в приведенных вариантах решений.